# Rich-text-editor to textarea not synching

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have used a rich-text-editor in my form which replaces my textarea element with its JavaScript code and when I click on submit button it writes into the textarea and sends the data as the textarea input to action page.
but when I submits the form for first time I do not get the text at first click on submit button. It has to click on submit button twice to get the text in textarea and action page. I think syncing of data from rich-text-editor to the textarea input is not taking place at first click but in second.
what should I do?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: the best course of action is to hire a developer, the second is to post the code here and try to solve this together